# How to convert guzzle response (from image url) to base64

Tags: php, base64, guzzle

I try to download image with guzzle and then convert the response to base64 without storing in local path.
In my project I have a function to get the response from guzzle, with below code, and then I want to know how can I convert the response `$body` to a base64 string.

```php
$response = $this->client->request(
    $req_type,
    $Url,
    [
        'body' => $post_data,
        'connect_timeout' => $TimeOut,
        'verify' => false,
        //'debug' => $debug,
        'cookies' => $cookiejarlocal,
    ]
);

$body = $response->getBody();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$body = (string)$response->getBody();
$base64 = base64_encode($body);
```

Comment: Yes, PHP.net is a wonderful documentation resource for users of PHP, [base64_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).